# Raspberry Pi 2 : DHT11 : Oracle Java ME Embedded

Tags: sensor, java, temperature, dht22

Anyone integrated DHT11 temperature sensor on Raspberry Pi2 with Oracle Java ME Embedded system?

Any direction will be helpful.

Comment: I doubt it is possible.  The DHT11 needs accurate timings of the order of 25 µs or so and there is no evidence that Java on the Pi can support such resolution reliably.

Comment: So do i need to change sensor or ?

Comment: If it's just temperature you want you could try a DS18B20 1-wire sensor.  The Linux kernel has drivers for that and the sensor value can be read from a file.  The Linux kernel also has drivers for the DHT11/22 but I have had no success in using the DHT11/22 kernel driver.

Comment: ok. Will try out.